# Fluorescence lifetime imaging

Tags: optics

Actually I am not a physics student but I have to give a lecture about Fluorescence lifetime imaging(FLIM). I am thinking of comparing this techniques to another imaging techniques.
Does anyone know what is the best imaging techniques that is comparable to FLIM?
Thank you

Soha

Comment: I actually voted to close this as "primarily opinion-based", not "too broad". Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is kind of trivial, nonetheless I find that many people do not grasp the following points at first glance and struggle under the weight of the misconceptions that follow.

You might try making the analogy between FLIM and doppler shift imaging, such as used in echocardiograms, or with interferometry or even a rainfall plot as a function of position over a map. The point being is that the FLIM image reports properties of the imaged specimen as a function of position that are unrelated to the light's intensity. Each pixel in the FLIM image assumes that fluorescence with a good enough signal to noise can be gathered from the corresponding position in the imaged specimen. *Given that this is so* (otherwise the image for poor SNR pixels is simply garbage) the FLIM image reports how long fluorescence takes to emerge from each point in the sample after excitation. Sometimes the FLIM image "looks like a conventional image" (i.e. a brightfield microscopy image) but this is only insofar that the cellular structures imaged correspond to different chemical compositions and therefore different fluorescence interactions with the driving light.